# Count substring in string

Tags: python, strings, comparative-review

With the comments on the same line as the code, it refers to. e.g

```
NumBob = 0
s = 'sexbobombob'
i = range(len(s)+1) #Generates a list from 0 to the length of s
u = 0 # This would be the variable storing each value of the list
for ans in i: # this allows me to extract each value of i
    if ans > 0: # Completely arbitrary. i just used any condition that allows me to pick up all values in the list.
        u = ans
    x = s[u:u+3] #By using indexing to pick u, u+1, and u +2 i can pick up 3 letters at a time
    if "bob" in x: # Checking if the term i picked up is a Bob
        numBob += 1 # increasing the Bob count
print "Number of times bob occurs is:" + str(numBob) # Printing the number of Bobs
```

With the comments beneath the line of code, it refers to. e.g

```
numBob = 0
s = 'sexbobombob'
i = range(len(s)+1)
#Generates a list from 0 to the length of s
u = 0
# This would be the variable storing each value of the list
for ans in i:
    # this allows me to extract each value of i
    if ans > 0:
        # Completely arbitrary. i just used any condition that allows me to pick up all values in the list.
        u = ans
    x = s[u:u+3]
    #By using indexing to pick u, u+1, and u +2 i can pick up 3 letters at a time
    if "bob" in x:
        # Checking if the term i picked up is a Bob
        numBob += 1
        # increasing the Bob count
print "Number of times bob occurs is:" + str(numBob) 
#Printing the number of Bobs
```

Or with the comments preceding the line of code. e.g

```
numBob = 0
s = 'sexbobombob'
#Generates a list from 0 to the length of s
i = range(len(s)+1)
# This would be the variable storing each value of the list
u = 0
# this allows me to extract each value of i
for ans in i:
    # Completely arbitrary. i just used any condition that allows me to pick up all values in the list.
    if ans > 0:
        u = ans
    # By using indexing to pick u, u+1, and u +2 i can pick up 3 letters at a time
    x = s[u:u+3]
    # Checking if the term i picked up is a Bob
    if "bob" in x:
        # increasing the Bob count
        numBob += 1
        # Printing the number of Bobs
print "Number of times bob occurs is:" + str(numBob)
```

Comment: It's recommended to follow the style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 5):

Using this kind of all-top-level short-named fully imperative style forces you to rely heavily on comments to make the code readable.

Comments everywhere repeating the code violate the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle:

```
    # increasing the Bob count
    numBob += 1
```

You just doubled reading / maintaining time here.

Descriptive names, examples of usage and sometimes functional style make "how"-kind comments unnecessary:

```
def count(substring, string):
    """
    >>> count("bob","bobhejrhaabobfqbqsanbobb")
    3
    """
    return sum(substring == group for group in groups(string, len(substring)))

def groups(xs, n):
    """
    >>> groups([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
    """
    for i in range(len(xs)-n):
        yield xs[i:i+n]
```

The code looks self explaining to me, but feel free to ask about any doubts about it.

Comment: Even simpler: `def count(substring, string): return sum(string.startswith(substring, i) for i in range(len(string) - len(substring)))`